# Firefox addon to search Google using "site:[current-website]" keyword?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, google-search

I'm wondering is there an addon that lets you search (using default search bar preferably) the website in the current tab in Google with the "site:" keyword? This way I don't have to write the keyword and the URL every time I want to search a website in Google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reviews for [Current Site Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/57674), the add-on from [Ignacio's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/130158/firefox-addon-to-search-google-using-sitecurrent-website-keyword/130163#130163), mentioned [Search Site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14381). It sounds a lot less intrusive than Current Site Search, and is what I decided to install.

Comment: Nice integration with the search bar, just what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another, although much more "pumped up" extension that will do the job, is [Fastest Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fastest-search/). If you already have installed it, but didn't know about this feature (as I did, before coming here), you can use the shortcut "gsd" (Google SubDomain) in order to search with "site:".

I found the extension when trying to resolve an issue I had with [InstantFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/?src=ss) and discovered it is a lot better for me (except for the visual part:). It did not actually solve my issue, but that's another story... I just give the InstantFox example, because most people know this extension and can get an idea what Fastest Search is about.

Answer (score 1):

A little poking around [found this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/57674).

Comment: I like Search Site (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14381) better, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Bar Lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/492). You can click search and drop from the pull down "current site" or edit its preferences and place the button right there. It also anonymizes your Google ID so they can't track your searches. But you need to ENABLE this in the preferences first!